# UserID Function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, hash

I'm trying to generate a UserID out of userAgent and Date Function. I also wanted to understand callback function (which I still didn't get (JS Noob)). Therefore I built the following example:

```
var storage = window.localStorage; 
var storageUserId = storage.getItem("userID"); 
var text = "";  

function userID(callback){
  var agent = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var now = new Date(); 
    try{
        callback(agent, now);
    }catch(e){}
}

function hasher(agent,now){
    var hash = 0;
    var arr = []; 
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
      var pars = arguments[i]; 
      for(var j = 0; j < pars.length; j++){
         var charI = pars.charCodeAt(j);
         hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+charI;
         hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
         hash = hash.toString();
      }
    }
  console.log(hash + "|" + hash);
}

userID(hasher);
```

The result should look like this "9834917834|8293479273" (example numbers to show format). First number hashed agent second number hashed date. I got the hash logic form here: http://mediocredeveloper.com/wp/?p=55

Maybe there is a better way to do this :)

I really appreciate your help!

Thanks a lot!

Best, 
Anton

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Imo the callback wrapper is not necessary and only needed, if you want to manage multiple `hasher()` alternatives at the same time.

Comment: `hash` gets different values in every iteration. When doing `hash + "|" + hash` you just output the result of the last iteration twice.

Comment: Thanks! @JonasW. how should i rewrite hash + "|" + hash that format "9834917834|8293479273" comes out?

Answer (score 1):

You should extract the hashing loop into a new function:

```
function hash(str){
  var hash = 0;
  for(const char of str){        
    const charCode =  char.charCodeAt(0);            
    hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+charCode;
  }
  hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer

  return hash.toString();
}
```

So to get the hash you want to you just need to call it twice:

```
function getUserID(){
  return hash(window.navigator.userAgent) + "|" + hash("" + new Date);
}
```

(PS: you know that `new Date` will change every millisecond?)

Comment: Perfect! Yes I'm aware of that.

Comment: Hi Jonas, just one further question: I can't use ECMA script. Is there maybe another way to write the hash function? Thanks!

Comment: @Toni2708 what?? You know that javascript *is* ECMAscript?

Comment: Google Tag Manager doesn't support ECMA script features. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: What does it support then?